# Circuitikz and perpendicular coordinates in ConTeXt

Tags: context, circuitikz

I have a compilation error when I try to use perpendicular coordinates in circuitikz with ConTeXt :

```
\usemodule[tikz]

\usemodule[circuitikz]
\ctikzset{current=european, voltage=european, resistor=european, inductor=european}

\starttext
\startcircuitikz
  \draw (0, 0)
  node [en amp, noinv input up] (ALI) {}
  (ALI.+) -- ++(-1, 0) coordinate (A)
  (ALI.-) -- ++(0, -1.5) coordinate (B)
  to [R, l=$R_1$] (ALI.out |- B); 
\stopcircuitikz
\stoptext
```

I get the following error :

```
Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `out' (in 'out |- B')
```

I also tried to use `(ALI.out) coordinate (S)` and then `(S |- B)`
to avoid the dot operator in the coordinate name, but the error stays. Looking at the other posts I don't see any usual error in my code. Is there a problem with ConTeXt and circuitikz ?

Thank in advance,

Comment: Please note that this has been fixed in context `2024.01.08`

Comment: Notice that this should have been [fixed in Context since release 2024.01.08](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/763#issuecomment-1888229194).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seem to have been changes in the setup of the Ti*k*Z picture in `context`; somehow, the simple "aliasing" of `\startcircuitikz` is not working anymore. The good news is that the `circuitikz` environment does nothing (and I am considering removing it from the manual). In your case,

```latex
\usemodule[tikz]

\usemodule[circuitikz]
\ctikzset{current=european, voltage=european, resistor=european, inductor=european}

\starttext
\starttikzpicture
  \draw (0, 0)
  node [en amp, noinv input up] (ALI) {}
  (ALI.+) -- ++(-1, 0) coordinate (A)
  (ALI.-) -- ++(0, -1.5) coordinate (B)
  to [R, l=$R_1$] (ALI.out |- B); 
\stoptikzpicture
\stoptext
```

Seems to work ok. Anyway, I'll try to check what's happening.

[image]

Comment: This works wonderfully and is so simple. Thank you very much !

Comment: `|` is active in ConTeXt, so I would guess that that's the underlying issue here.

Comment: @MaxChernoff I applied the fix to my source https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/763, but the main file is in the context distribution, so I have to find a way to report it there...

Comment: @Rmano The best thing would be to send the whole file as an attachment to the ConTeXt mailing list [`ntg-context@ntg.nl`](https://mailman.ntg.nl/archives/list/ntg-context@ntg.nl/latest). Hans will probably apply the patch right away, but the update server is currently down, so it might be awhile before the fix is actually distributed. `\usemodule[t][circuitikz]` should force loading of your version in the interim (untested).

Comment: @MaxChernoff thanks for the hints. I have contacted Aditya and they will send the patch upstream!

Answer (score 3):

ConTeXt sets up `|` as an active character (catcode 13) while Ti*k*Z expects an "other" `|` (catcode 12). This means that you actually typed in `|13=12`, but Ti*k*Z is only looking for `|12=12`.

`\startcircuitikz` is defined as a delimited macro

```tex
% Lines 131--134 of m-circuitikz.mkxl
\aliased\let\stopcircuitikz\relax

\permanent\protected\def\startcircuitikz#1\stopcircuitikz
  {\starttikzpicture#1\stoptikzpicture}
```

so the catcodes are "frozen" in when the argument is scanned in. `\starttikzpicture` takes no arguments, so it *is* able to scan the `|` with the appropriate catcode.

To fix this, we can either alias `\startcircuitikz` directly to `\starttikzpicture`:

```tex
\usemodule[circuitikz]

\let\startcircuitikz\starttikzpicture
\let\stopcircuitikz\stoptikzpicture

\startTEXpage[offset=1em]
\startcircuitikz
    \draw (0, 0) to (0, 0 -| 1, 1);
\stopcircuitikz
\stopTEXpage
```

or, we can manually correct `|`'s catcode:

```tex
\usemodule[circuitikz]

\catcode`\|=12

\startTEXpage[offset=1em]
\startcircuitikz
    \draw (0, 0) to (0, 0 -| 1, 1);
\stopcircuitikz
\stopTEXpage
```

Both options give the same output:

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks, I will use your first suggestion in the next release.