# Circuitikz and transformer core in ConTeXt

Tags: context, circuitikz

I discover that circuitikz is available in ConTeXt, and since it is way more complete than the circuits.ee.IEC tikz library, I am considering switching to it. However, I can't display a transformer core (I updated my context distribution this morning to be sure there wasn't an update). Here is my MWE :

```
\usemodule[tikz]

\usemodule[circuitikz]
\ctikzset{current=european, voltage=straight, resistor=european, inductor=american}

\starttext
\starttikzpicture
  \draw (0, 0) node [transformer core] (T) {};  % asking for node[transformer] (T) {} works
\stoptikzpicture
\stoptext
```

The demand for `transformer core` leads to the following error

```
Control sequence expected instead of undefined
```

Of course I can recreate the core symbol using the transformer anchors, but it seems silly since it is already defined in the library… Is there a simple fix for this problem ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/705661/circuitikz-and-perpendicular-coordinates-in-context. Seems that you have the similar problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CircuiTi*k*Z attempts to use the `\pgfmoveto` macro which has been deprecated since 2005. `pgf` loads the compatibility packages by default under LaTeX, but not under ConTeXt. So strictly speaking, this bug isn't exclusive to ConTeXt as the following LaTeX document gives the same error:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[version=latest]{pgf}  % Works if this line is removed

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0, 0) node [transformer core] (T) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To fix this problem, you just need to provide appropriate definitions for `\pgfmoveto` and `\pgflineto`:

```tex
\usemodule[circuitikz]

\let\pgfmoveto=\pgfpathmoveto  % Added
\let\pgflineto=\pgfpathlineto  % Added

\startTEXpage
\starttikzpicture
    \node [transformer core] {};
\stoptikzpicture
\stopTEXpage
```

[image: output]

Comment: It works perfectly indeed !

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize it was even used. I'll fix it as soon as I can. Thanks (again)

Comment: Done, at https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/763